Banno Plugin Framework Bridge Working on iOS but Not on Android and Web Browser
I’m working with the @jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge to integrate a custom plugin within the Banno Online and Mobile apps. The plugin works perfectly on iOS, but I’m running into issues where the same functionality doesn’t work as expected on Android and in web browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). Here are the details:
•   Banno Plugin Bridge Version: @jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge (v1.0.0)
•   iOS App: Working as expected (link handling, routing, etc.)
•   Android App: No response when interacting with links.
•   Web Browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox): Links don’t trigger any actions. The router appears to be inactive.

I have put a debugger in the enableRouter function and inspected it looks like we are posting the message to the parent and the message looks like this {
"data": {
"href": "https://ui.dev.app-equipifi.com/?jwe_token=Bearer+&tct-id=tectonRoute.EquipifiEnhancedSso.Main&page=plans",
"external": false
},
"type": "click-link"
}
• I expected similar behavior as on iOS, but it seems like the Android app is not recognizing the postMessage events.
• I have checked the setup for both platforms and followed the instructions for setting up the links with target="_top".
For all platforms, if I am using an href link with target _top it should show me the expanded view of my application

Thanks for this info! If you wouldn't mind sharing some sample code that is able to reproduce the problem would be the most helpful - ideally using the simple example (https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example) so we can debug further

Just to add more context while I work on a sample code, I’m using the Banno Plugin Framework Bridge as outlined in this documentation to handle link interactions in our app. Specifically, I want to trigger an expanded view when a user interacts with an  tag (href) in our app. And the href is routing to https://ui.dev.app-equipifi.com/?jwe_token=Bearer+&tct-id=tectonRoute.EquipifiEnhancedSso.Main&page=plans

If you were able to share the code sample would still be most helpful - ideally using our simple plugin example to best be able for us to try and reproduce and debug

I took a look at the simple plugin and am not sure what I can provide from there that would help debug this issue but I can provide our html setup --> https://gist.github.com/kiduskinfe-equipifi/7ed2e649f493ef99fd3d9ed82256a910

Our bundlejs is created using webpack and we are using React library... please let me know if there is anything specific about our setup I can provide to help debug

Looking at what you shared, the one thing that comes to mind is the location of the enableRouter at the bottom of the  tag could cause issues in terms of the sequence of things loading. You might look into using a DOMContentLoaded event handler.

I’m currently using the following approach to enable routing in my Banno plugin:    .
Question:
Could there be any device-specific or browser-specific reasons why enableRouter would work only on iOS fi app(garden fi) but not on Android or web browsers? Are there any known compatibility issues or additional steps required to ensure consistent behavior across all platforms?

using DOMContentLoaded didn't seem to solve the issue

is there a sample code that you can share to show how the routing is handled after the message is posted to the parent?

from the banno-pluggin-framework-bridge.js I can see this code being executed
https://gist.github.com/kiduskinfe-equipifi/1b726f352a3049e1d70eb2c503ae0aa6
and I was able to add our app into an iframe and listen for the message that's being sent from banno-pluggin-framework-bridge.js and I was able to receive the message

Based on what little I can see with how you're rendering the plugin card face,I wonder if there are platform-specific differences in how webviews pull down web content and also differences in how the timing of rendering occurs? The gist above doesn't really have any user-interactive content in the HTML, so my assumption is that it's rendered after-the-fact client side. That would get at my hypothesis that the router can't 'see' your anchor tags since they may not exist at the time it runs.

To follow up on the above - it would be the most helpful to troubleshoot if you could provide a full reproducible example using the Basic Plugin Example (https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example). That would help fill in the missing context.

I have updated this https://gist.github.com/kiduskinfe-equipifi/7ed2e649f493ef99fd3d9ed82256a910. to include the user interaction

I do wonder what the bundle-825f0a0local-test.js contains, and what it's doing. It's possible that is interacting in conflict, somehow. I'm also curious what happens if you pull the import statement up into something like the <head> (meaning import { enableRouter } from "/js/banno-plugin-framework-bridge.js") and then running enableRouter(); when you know for sure the DOM is actually ready.

We use react for our UI and when we build our react app it creates a bundle.js file... so essentially it has all our ui logic. And I have tried moving the enableRouter in the head and that also didn't work

https://www.loom.com/share/d0265b39edb14aaebfbac0b10e5e885b?sid=0c171e8f-18cb-45f9-81de-3612193a86f8. Please let me know if you’re able to access this recording. It includes a walkthrough of what’s happening in the app.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QR3_mDQO4OIkXHyq1dsY65tqmKhYd26j/view and this is on IOS mobile app

We found the issue.. thanks for the support @JaimeLopezJr. and Team

What was the issue? It would be great for you to add your own answer (and accept the answer) so that other folks can benefit from your findings.
